# Fragmentation and GUID clustered key

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm trying to understand why a GUID clustered index produces high fragmentation / page splits?

Comment: It doesn't, necessarily. Whether it does depends on *how* you're generating the `GUID` values. If you're using `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` or it's moral equivalents (e.g. `UuidCreateSequential`) then your assertion is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

The data type is never the root cause for fragmentation. Fragmentation arises when you add additional data onto pages which do not have space free. This leads to a page split.

There are 2 common reasons for this:

1. Inserts at random places at random places in the B-tree
2. Updates increasing the size of a row (at random places in the B-tree)

Guids are usually case (1), except if generated in a sequential way (`NEWSEQUENTIALID`).